# Batch standard error redirection (2>NUL) causes .exe to crash?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, child-process

When I run a program called `KLRINT.EXE` from the windows command prompt, not all standard output is redirected to `terminal-output.txt` as instructed:

```
KLRINT.EXE  0<terminal-input.txt 1>terminal-output.txt
    
  ...some output goes here...
```

The remaining 90% of the program's output is redirected successfully to `terminal-output.txt`. The program itself executes successfully and exits with error code 0:

```
echo %errorlevel%
0
```

The source code for `KLRINT.EXE` is long gone, so, where is `...some output goes here...` coming from? My initial guess was that it was standard error. If I try to redirect standard error to `2>NUL` or `2>terminal-error.txt`, the program crashes with error code 255 at the point where `...some output goes here...` is to be printed to standard output:

```
KLRINT.EXE  0<terminal-input.txt 1>terminal-output.txt 2>terminal-error.txt

echo %errorlevel%
255
```

Note nothing appears in `terminal-error.txt`.

Bottom line is that **any attempt to access or redirect standard error causes the problem to crash**. Is there another way to access or spoof standard error without causing the program to crash? If so, I believe I can solve for my larger / resulting problem described below.

The ultimate goal of this project is to call `KLRINT.EXE` from a Node.js app. When doing so, Node.js, rightfully so, always tries to access and return standard error. This, in turn, causes the program to crash with error code 255. FWIW, I'm using the native Node.js module / function `child_process.exec()`.

```
exec('KLRINT.EXE  0<terminal-input.txt', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error){console.log(error);}
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Here is the error object returned from `exec()`:

```
Error: Command failed: KLRINT.EXE  0<terminal-input.txt

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:326:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:453:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:665:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 255,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'KLRINT.EXE  0<terminal-input.txt'
}
```

I'm left with no way to invoke `KLRINT.EXE` from a runtime such as Node.js.

Comment: If redirecting output causes a program to crash, you have a poorly-coded program that you should rewrite from scratch.

Comment: Maybe not, there is no requirements to support redirection. And you trade off features. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/high-level-console-input-and-output-functions

Comment: Does the same error happen with `2>&1` at the cmd prompt?

Comment: I figured out that all output consolidates if I go with 1>terminal-output.txt 2>&1. For some reason, when I try to run the exact same command (or .bat file containing the command) from Node.js it crashes. I also tried from Java and it crashed at the exact same point. Arggh!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to employ a workaround and wanted to close-out on this thread. I noticed the application would crash if called directly from Java or Node, but would execute successfully if called from Windows Task Scheduler. As such, decided to create a windows task and invoke it from my Node application by way of the application event logger using node-windows module.